# generate random binary data such 23ABFF

Tags: java, random, types

I want to generate binary data the similar to OData binary and I not sure how.
the type is defined as

```
Represent fixed- or variable- length binary data
binary'[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]*' OR X '[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]*' NOTE: X and binary are case sensitive. Spaces are not allowed between binary and the quoted portion. Spaces are not allowed between X and the quoted portion. Odd pairs of hex digits are not allowed.

**Example 1: X'23AB' Example 2: binary'23ABFF'**
```

with the next.random() Im not sure which type can be appropriate  .
any idea?

Comment: is converting a random int to hex an option for you? this is perhaps not the best, but may be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Random().nextBytes(byte[])
```

**EDIT:** You can also achieve this with

```
new Random().nextInt(16)
```

See:

```
int nbDigitsYouWant=8;
Random r=new Random();
for(int i=0;i<nbDigitsYouWant;i++){
  //display hexa representation
  System.out.print(String.format("%x",r.nextInt(16)));
}
```

Output:

```
ea0d3b9d
```

**EDIT :** Here is a quick and dirty example with random bytes sent to a DataOutputStream.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/path/to/your/file"));

  int nbDesiredBytes=99999999;
  int bufferSize=1024;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
  Random r=new Random();

  int nbBytes=0;
  while(nbBytes<nbDesiredBytes){
    int nbBytesToWrite=Math.min(nbDesiredBytes-nbBytes,bufferSize);
    byte[] bytes=new byte[nbBytesToWrite];
    r.nextBytes(bytes);
    dos.write(bytes);
    nbBytes+=nbBytesToWrite;
  }

  dos.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you,I need to return the value of the binary so what should be the java type for it,I don't see where you define the type of binary in the model...

Comment: Then byte or byte[] is the best type. I updated the post with a quick and dirty example to generate random bytes to a DataOutputStream.